# AngularJS and template files hosted on a different domain

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, angularjs

This is a basic HTTP question and doesn't fully relate to AngularJS, but since AngularJS takes care of all the template downloading and processing then is it possible to host the template files (static HTML) on a different domain or subdomain and have it work? I'm guessing no since this breaks the XHR same-origin policy that browsers enforce, but I'm hoping that AngularJS has a method of working around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get that to work if you set the correct headers. Check out the [CORS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) for more details.